# No prompt for username and password when adding service reference

Tags: .net, visual-studio, web-services, visual-studio-2022

On my old computer (VS2019), when I adding a service reference, I had a prompt for send username and password.
Since i changed computer and version of VS (2022) I am not able to add a service reference. The prompt do not appear and I have the following error :

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'

Usually, after adding the reference service with VS 2019, I change the app.config to change Authentication method to NTLM.

Is there a way to bring back the prompt or i missed something when I installed the new computer ?

Comment: I did some tests : My computer is connected to Azure AD. I have tested with a local account and the prompt bringed back.